# typescript loop through object and create a new object by transforming the values

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given the following Object,

```
const document = {
  id: 'f8bbe6dd-25e3-464a-90e2-c39038d030e5',
  fields:   {
    lastname: 'TestLastName',
    firstname: 'TestFirstName' 
  } 
}
```

how can I transform it to an object of the interface Hit using typescript/javascript?

```
export interface Hit {
  id: string;
  fields: { [key: string]: string[] };
}
```

Expected result is as follows.

```
document = {
  id: 'f8bbe6dd-25e3-464a-90e2-c39038d030e5',
  fields:   {
    lastname: [
      'TestLastName'
    ],
    firstname: [
      'TestFirstName'
    ]
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a little function which maps object properties, sort of like map, but for objects.

```
type Hash<T> = {[index: string]: T};

function map<T, U>(
  obj: Hash<T>,
  fn: (val: T, prop?: string, obj?: any) => U,
  thisObj?
): Hash<U> {
  const result: Hash<U> = {};

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => result[key] = fn.call(thisObj, obj[key], key, obj));

  return result;
}
```

Then apply this to your `fields` property:

```
function transform(obj): Hit {
  const {id, fields} = obj;

  return {id, fields: map(obj.fields, x => [x])};
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you don't need a more generic solution:

```
newDocument = {id: document.id, fields: {lastname: [document.fields.lastname], firstname: [document.fields.firstname]} }
```

Comment: Thank You for responding. I need a more generic solution though.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split

```
export interface Hit {
  id: string;
  fields: Field;
}

export interface Field {
  [index: string]:string[];
}
```

Inspired from below answer you can see at [another stachoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914271/typescript-interface-definition-with-an-unknown-property-key)

```
export interface IMeta{}
export interface IValue{}
export interface IFunkyResponse {
     [index: string]:IValue[];
}
export interface IResponse {
     meta: IMeta;
}

export class Response implements IResponse {
    meta:IMeta;
    values:IValue[];
    books:IValue[];
    anything:IValue[];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure if you read my question, but your solution is irrelevant to the question I asked.

Comment: your problem is [key: string]: string[] line right where key can be anything ?

Comment: Ofcourse, but what does that have any thing to do with splitting the interface? I'm not looking for an interface definition.

Comment: try to get some hints from the link I shared. you can create a wild card there. its just reference. if it does not help try something else