# Property is not assignable to string index in interface

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript2.0

I have the following interfaces:

```
export interface Meta {
  counter: number;
  limit: number;
  offset: number;
  total: number;
}

export interface Api<T> {
  [key: string]: T[];
  meta: Meta; // error
}
```

Currently, I'm receiving the following error:

> Property 'meta' of type 'Meta' is not assignable to string index
>   type 'T[]'.

After searching a bit, I found this statement in [**TS docs**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html):

> While string index signatures are a powerful way to describe the
>   “dictionary” pattern, they also enforce that all properties match
>   their return type. This is because a string index declares that
>   obj.property is also available as obj["property"].

Does it means that when I have a string index signature, I can't have any other variable without match this type?

Actually I can get rid of this error declaring the interface like this:

```
export interface Api<T> {
  [key: string]: any; // used any here
  meta: Meta;
}
```

Doing this, I lose the completely ability of type inference. Is there any way to do this without this ugly way?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of two interfaces:

```
interface Api<T> {
    [key: string]: T[];  
}

type ApiType<T> = Api<T> & {
    meta: Meta;
}

declare let x: ApiType<string>;

let a = x.meta // type of `a` is `Meta`
let b = x["meta"]; // type of `b` is `Meta`

let p = x["someotherindex"] // type of `p` is `string[]`
let q = x.someotherindex // type of `q` is `string[]`
```

Comment: Thanks. It was really helpful :) Just a simple note... here `declare let x: Api<string>;` shouldn't be `declare let x: ApiType<string>;`?

Comment: Yes it should be.

Comment: Having this same issue when working with DefinitelyTyped defintions, when trying to extend an interface. Is there a way to extend an interface that has this string index? e.g.
`
// main declaration
interface Api<T> {
    [key: string]: T[];
}

// in extension file
interface Api<T> {
    // extend interface
    test: T;
}

declare let x: ApiType<string>;

let a = x.test;
`

Comment: taking from the method in this answer, its simply a matter of separating the string indexes and the properties/methods into separate classes, then mashing them together with &.  example: type ChildType<T> = ParentTypeStringIndexes<T> & ParentTypeFunctions<T> & ParentTypeProperties<T> & {....}, where otherwise it would have looked like: interface ChildType<T> extends ParentTypeStringIndexes<T>, ParentTypeFunctions<T>, ParentTypeProperties<T> {....}

Comment: OTOH we cannot do this extending ApiType like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23914271/typescript-interface-definition-with-an-unknown-property-key

Comment: This seems like hack/workaround for a more fundamental issue: that TypeScript interfaces do not have an "`additionalProperties`" mechanism like JSON Schema does. Your solution works when *defining* a type, but fails when *implementing* it. In your example, try assigning a value to `x`, like `x = { meta: new Meta(), someotherindex: ['abc'] }`. You'll get an error. I would post a link to TypeScript Playground, but it’s too long for SO comments.

Comment: @chharvey exactly what i have just faced, i want to initialize the variable right away but getting the same error, any other solution to have the assignment working too?

Comment: @chharvey: I cannot make it fail, can you share an example? (with a url shorter you can share a playground). tinyurl.com/wq5kvza

Comment: @tokland : You forgot to assign a type to `x` when you initialized it. You should get an error when assigning it type `ApiType<string>`.

Comment: I was able to use "intersection" approach without declaring additional types to intersect.  type AssetsType = {
 [key: string]: AssetType,
} & {
 badges: {
  [key in TRarity | 'all']: number
 }
}

Answer (score 17):

The presented best solution didn't work when I've tried to implement this interface. I ended up nesting part with dynamic key. Maybe someone will find it useful:

```
interface MultichannelConfiguration {
  channels: {
    [key: string]: Configuration;
  }
  defaultChannel: string;
}
```