# How to dynamically set types on object with dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this list of dishes:

```js
const dishes = [
    {
      id: 'dish01',
      title: 'SALMON CRUNCH',
      price: 99,
      ingredients: [
        'SALMON',
        'CRUNCH SALAD',
      ],
      options: [
        {
          option: 'BASE',
          choices: ['RICE', 'SPAGHETTI', 'MIX'],
          defaultOption: 'MIX',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 'dish02',
      title: 'GOCHUJANG CHICKEN',
      price: 110,
      ingredients: [
        'GOCHUJANG',
        'CHICKEN',
      ],
      options: [
        {
          option: 'BASE',
          choices: ['RICE', 'SPAGHETTI', 'MIX'],
          defaultOption: 'MIX',
        },
        {
          option: 'TOPPING',
          choices: ['MAYO', 'KETCHUP', 'NONE'],
          defaultOption: 'NONE',
        },
      ],
    },
...
]
```

I then decide to use a `useReducer` (React) to keep track and build a single dish order object that goes into the card.

Is it then possible define a custom interface for each dish?

```js
// types for dish01
type Ingredients = 'SALMON' | 'CRUNCH SALAD'

interface DishOrder {
  id: string
  withoutIngredients: Ingredients[]
  BASE: 'RICE' | 'SPAGHETTI' | 'MIX'
}

// types for dish02
type Ingredients = 'GOCHUJANG' | 'CHICKEN'

interface DishOrder {
  id: string
  withoutIngredients: Ingredients[]
  BASE: 'RICE' | 'SPAGHETTI' | 'MIX'
  TOPPINGS: 'MAYO' | 'KETCHUP' | 'NONE'
}
```

if not, is this then as typed as it can get:

```js
interface DishOptions {
  [key: string]: string
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/45261035/618099
type DishOrder = DishOptions & {
  id: string
  withoutIngredients: string[]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a perfect case for [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)?

```
type Ingredients = 'SALMON' | 'CRUNCH SALAD'

interface DishOrder<T> {
  id: string
  withoutIngredients: T[]
  BASE: 'RICE' | 'SPAGHETTI' | 'MIX'
  TOPPINGS: 'MAYO' | 'KETCHUP' | 'NONE'
}

// const yourDishOrder: DishOrder<Ingredients> = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```js
enum Ingredient {
  Salmon = "Salmon",
  CrunchSalad = "Crunch Salad",
  ...
}

enum Base {
  Ris = "Ris",
  ...
}

enum Topping {
  Mayo = "Mayo",
  ...
}

interface DishOrder {
  id: string;
  withoutIngredients: Ingredient[];
  toppings?: Topping[];
  base: Base[];
}
```

this is not an extreme case at all.

Comment: Thank you for this very quick reply and suggestion. It looks interesting and like a better approach than the last resort I suggested. Do the types have to be 'typed' or can I code something that declares the types?

Comment: It might not be an extreme case :D but I quickly go to the deeper end of pool instead of just staying longer in the "kiddie" pool.

Comment: I'm afraid they have to be typed. Unless you have an array of options somewhere

Comment: If I did then how would I then do it?

Comment: I think in such a case enums would not make much sense. I would suggest doing something like this:
```
const ingredientsOptionsArray = [...] as const;
export type Ingredient = (typeof ingredientsOptionsArray)[number]
```
here's a similar example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA2gIjmgNDNAjbXYNAXXghlEigCgoBPABwFMYBBJGACgZZADN4AShRgArgFs8zAE4kgA

Comment: Getting into the deeper end ;-) - thank you! Will give it a look. Thinking that I can construct the array from my `const dishes` array

Comment: Newbie question: what why is it `[number]` and not just `[]` ?

Comment: Because you want to get the type of the result of getting the value of a numeric key. `(typeof ingretientsOptionsArray)[]` would mean an array of arrays of ingredient strings