# Typing a reducer state (holding initialState) by chaining interections together (to build a sorta one-time recursive type)

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

Building this reducer with typescript and are trying to combine a lot of types together to archive something ala this typescript mockup:

```
type/interface DishOrderState {
  id: string
  withoutIngredients: string[]
  [key: string]: string
  initialState: {
     id: string
     withoutIngredients: string[]
     [key: string]: string
  }
}
```

a `state` could look like this

```js
{
  id: '123'
  withoutIngredients: ['tomato'],
  ["BASE"]: 'rice',
  initialState: {
    id: '123'
    withoutIngredients: [],
    ["BASE"]: 'fries'
  }
}
```

My attempt to archive it looks like this so far:

```
export type DishActionType =
  | { type: 'REMOVE_INGREDIENT'; ingredient: string }
  | { type: 'ADD_INGREDIENT'; ingredient: string }
  | { type: 'PICK_OPTION'; option: string; choice: string }
  | { type: 'RESET' }
  | { type: 'never' }

interface DishOptions {
  [key: string]: string
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/45261035/618099
type DishOrder = DishOptions & {
  id: string
  withoutIngredients: string[]
}

type DishOrderState = DishOrder & {
  initialState: DishOrder
}

function dishOrderReducer(state :DishOrderState, action :DishActionType) :DishOrderState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REMOVE_INGREDIENT':
      return {
        ...state,
        withoutIngredients: [...state.withoutIngredients.push(action.ingredient).sort()],
      }
    case 'ADD_INGREDIENT':
      return {
        ...state,
        withoutIngredients: [...state.withoutIngredients].filter(
          (ingredient) => ingredient != action.ingredient
        ),
      }
    case 'PICK_OPTION':
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.option]: action.choice
      }]
    case 'RESET':
      return {
        ...state.initialState,
        initialState: {...state.initialState}
      }
    default:
      throw new Error(`No action case for this action type: ${action.type}`)
  }
}
```

But vscode screams at me with

```
(property) withoutIngredients: string[]
Type '{ withoutIngredients: any[]; id: string; initialState: DishOrder; }' is not assignable to type 'DishOrderState'.
  Type '{ withoutIngredients: any[]; id: string; initialState: DishOrder; }' is not assignable to type 'DishOptions'.
    Property 'withoutIngredients' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

[image: showing the vscode error]

Hovering over the `DishOrderState` shows this:

```
type DishOrderState = DishOptions & {
    id: string;
    withoutIngredients: string[];
} & {
    initialState: DishOrder;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're mixing together *specific* fields, like `id: string`, with *indexed* fields like `[key: string] : string`.

An indexed field declaration says "there could be an infinite number of additional fields, but they'll all have this kind of key and this kind of value".  Think of it as a wildcard type of description.  That mostly ends up overriding any specific fields you might list.

Beyond that, a couple other observations:

Right now you're writing this reducer the hard way, by writing all the TS types and update logic by hand. You *should* be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) to write the reducer, which will drastically simplify the amount of code you have to write in terms of immutable updates and TS types for actions.  Also see [our official "Usage with TS" guide page](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript).

Beyond that, the state shape doesn't make much sense. For one thing, why is there a field called `initialState` nested inside of the state value?  That's very confusing.  Typically there's a variable named `initialState` defined outside the reducer, standalone, and the reducer references that by itself - it's not nested *inside* the state value.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I'm using React hook useReducer and not Redux

Comment: Fun fact: you can still use Redux Toolkit to write reducer functions that are only meant for use with `useReducer`!  A reducer is _just_ a function - doesn't matter how it was implemented inside.  And, RTK's `createSlice` lets you write reducer functions with minimal boilerplate and correct TS types.