# How to define one property type different from any others?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```js
interface Foo {
  bar: {};
  [key: string]: string;
}

// Property 'bar' of type '{}' is not assignable to string index type 'string'.
```

I'm trying to make property `bar` is `Object` and any other properties is string, how to define this without `any`?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i) and its answer for the issues surrounding such a "default" or "rest" index signature.  Translating the code from that answer yields [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOaORm).  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This error is is not about the `bar type` is is about the dictionary you defined `[key: string]: string;`. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45258216/property-is-not-assignable-to-string-index-in-interface).

But you can solve the problem like this:

```
interface Foo {
   [key: string]: string;
}

type MainFooType = Foo & {
   bar: Object;
}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIDaA1hAJ4BcyAzmFKAOYC6Vt9IDA3LgL665gyABxQBZOKAzoAKsJQBeNJmQAyHPgLIARnChUA8loBWEBGG58gA)

And the assignment can be:

```
const dictionary: { [key: string]: string } = { other: 'val2' };
let b: MainFooType = Object.assign({ bar: {} }, dictionary);

var f = b["bar"] // empty Object
var f1 = b["other"] // val2
```

Comment: it doesn't work if you actually want to assign to a variable of that type.[playgroud link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIDaA1hAJ4BcyAzmFKAOYC6Vt9IDA3LgL665gyABxQBZOKAzoAKsJQBeNJmQAyHPmQAjOFCoB5TQCsICMNz64ANhDDI4VcZMyyRyRXgLbdOHgBoN6GAAFtBUAORhvJxAA)

Comment: You are in the wrong assignment with your dictionary. you have to use `Object.assign` . See [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQDED2nUG9iqoDaA1lAJ4BcqAzhDOAOYC61dDYjA3MAL7DAI5AA5oAsgnBZMAFRFoAvBmyoAZHgKoARghjUA8loBWUJBB79gSTGDqoAJiDMgbuqnmJl37Jq1r0mVF5UJVxUTAgAC1hqAHIANwQAGwAmWKCeJKgIbWoJKWw5URDUQxMzADoEGhoQRjAACjCdPTxg3gAaBycIFzA3AEoeYESYVDgSrSIAIhbp5lQAekXUKABbYSFS41MIEd1xgEZJmYjomHmllcTUoA)

Comment: @xiaoxiyao I put the assignment part in my answer.