# Typescript error converting a type to anorther

Tags: typescript

I have a function that formats some data from a type to another.
Basically changes some case and flats some fields.

This is my code:

```js
const formatData = (data: Login): LoginFormatted => {
  return {
    Date: data.date,
    UserInfo: {
      name: data.user.name,
      email: data.user.email
    },
    ...data.otherFields
  };
};

const doThat = (data: Login) => {
  const dataFormatted = formatData(data);
  return dataFormatted;
};

const dataFormatted = doThat({
  date: "2000-12-01",
  user: {
    name: "Mary",
    email: "mary.lorem@something.com"
  },
  otherFields: { lastname: "Snow", city: "Berlin" }
});
```

And my types:

```js
export type Login = {
  date: string;
  user: {
    name: string;
    email: string;
  };
  otherFields?: { [key: string]: string };
};

export type LoginFormatted = {
  Date: string;
  UserInfo: {
    name: string;
    email: string;
  };
} & { [key: string]: string };
```

[HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-water-kpj6xu?file=/src/index.ts) the working code

I get a TypeScript error in `formatData`:

> Type '{ Date: string; UserInfo: { name: string; email: string; }; }'
> is not assignable to type 'LoginFormatted'.   Type '{ Date: string;
> UserInfo: { name: string; email: string; }; }' is not assignable to
> type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
> Property 'UserInfo' is incompatible with index signature.
> Type '{ name: string; email: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

What am I doing wrong?

I read these questions ([How to define Typescript type as a dictionary of strings but with one numeric "id" property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i), [Property is not assignable to string index in interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45258216/property-is-not-assignable-to-string-index-in-interface)), and I tried to modify my code like this but it still doesn't work:

```js
export interface Login {
  date: string;
  user: {
    name: string;
    email: string;
  };
  otherFields?: Other;
}

export type LoginFormatted = {
  Date: string;
  UserInfo: {
    name: string;
    email: string;
  };
} & Other;

interface Other {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define Typescript type as a dictionary of strings but with one numeric "id" property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i)

Comment: Read this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45258216/property-is-not-assignable-to-string-index-in-interface

Comment: @RickyMo No, I think the intent here was that `LoginFormatted` has mandatory fields `Date` and `UserInfo` _and also_ arbitrary other fields (as evident in the function), not "either `Date` and `UserInfo` _or_ arbitrary fields"

Comment: @Freestyle09 thank you for the reply. I read the answers but I didn't understand what I have to do. I that case the other properties could be string or number and this is not my case, right?

Comment: @Freestyle09 I tried to follow what in answer you post is described but I failed. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

I actually think that the other questions linked in the comments have better answers than this, but your question got me curious so I made a couple tries myself to see how TypeScript works in these cases.

##### Type Definition

On the Type Definition aspect, as far as I can see, everything works smoothly:

```
 type Combine = {
     Core: {
         Name: string;
         Colour: string;
     }
 } & { [key: string]: string }

 // then writing
 const combine: Combine = {... we'll see this...}
 combine.Core.Name // is prompted and doesn't give any error
 combine["attachment"] // this also doesn't give any error
```

So as far as the type `Combine` goes TypeScript seems to correctly add the `Core` field to a string-string dictionary.

##### Making Instances

Now the problem is how do we make an instance of that `Combine` type, because that's when TypeScript messes up.

```
// this gives the same error as you reported
const combine: Combine = {
    Core: {
       Name: "Wheatley",
       Colour: "Blue"
    }
}

// while this says "hey, it must include a Core field!" ಠ_ಠ
const combine: Combine = {
    attachment: "nope!"
}
```

I guess that's because when you define a dictionary the string-string check kicks in and doesn't let you declare other types, while when you correctly fallow the string-string constraint it realises it's missing the other `Core` field.

##### Solutions & Hacks

Now as I said the other questions have quite more in depth and clean answers to this issue, like leaving the dictionary to a separate sub-field without mixing it in with the `Core` field or making a multiple type dictionary instead of a strict string-string one.

Yet it really feels dumb to have it working like a charm when handling the actual instance but not being able to properly create one.

So I came up with this little "hack" which seems to work

```
const combine: Combine = {
    Core: {
       Name: "Wheatley",
       Colour: "Blue"
    }
    attachment: "nope!"
} as unknown as Combine
```

So basically you break TS typing and then put it back together.

So in your case would be enough to write something like:

```
const formatData = (data: Login): LoginFormatted => {
  return {
    Date: data.date,
    UserInfo: {
      name: data.user.name,
      email: data.user.email
    },
    ...data.otherFields
  } as unknown as LoginFormatted;
};
```

To get everything working.

Answer (score 0):

adjust the `loggingFormatted` to the following

```js
export type LoginFormatted = {
  [key: string]: string;
  Date: string;
  UserInfo: {
    name: string;
    email: string;
  };
};
```

this [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) will require `Date` and `UserInfo` while allowing extension with other properties.

Comment: while this works fine, you loose the typing of the dictionary, so if you write like `const test = loginFormatted["lastname"]` the variable `test` would be of type `any`. Also you could write something like `loginFormatted["lastname"] = Date.now()` which kinda breaks the whole string-string dictionary idea.

Comment: oops small mistake i corrected it to string :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better solution than this (thank you @Carlo Moretti):

```
const formatData = (data: Login): LoginFormatted => {
  return {
    Date: data.date,
    UserInfo: {
      name: data.user.name,
      email: data.user.email
    },
    ...data.otherFields
  } as unknown as LoginFormatted;
};
```

would be:

```
export type Login = {
  date: string;
  user: {
    name: string;
    email: string;
  };
  otherFields?: { [key: string]: string };
};

export type LoginFormatted = {
  Date: string;
  UserInfo: {
    name: string;
    email: string;
  };
} & { [key: string]: unknown };
```